# What are different between "/" and "\" (in open function )?

Tags: python

I 'm python beginner

I can't execute this code

```
with open('D:\Machine_learning_student_project\New folder\student-mat.csv','r') as f:
    a = csv.reader(f)
```

open function syntax 'mode' wont work

but when I change to "/"

```
with open('D:/Machine_learning_student_project/New folder/student-mat.csv','r') as f:
    a = csv.reader(f)
```

It just worked

Comment: Please post the error message. I got _...Malformed \N character..._

Comment: I don't use windows (mac and linux user), but I believe the issue has to do with `\\` being used to escape.

Comment: The traditional path separator on UNIX is the forward and on Windows the backward slash. Over time and versions Windows started to accept the forward slash as well, with some limitation of cause.

Comment: *Windows* doesn't accept it; Python automatically converts it when interacting with the Windows filesystem.

Comment: It is "/"   my date display 10/6/2565

Comment: @CrazyChucky: Most (almost all) Windows APIs accept `/` just fine. You can't use it in a DOS prompt (because `/` is for switches there), but Python is calling the raw WinAPI APIs, which are largely perfectly happy with either `/` or `\ `. Python rarely, if ever, needs to convert them. e.g. [The `CreateFile` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea): "You may use either forward slashes (/) or backslashes (\\) in this name."

Comment: @ tdelaney   File "<ipython-input-73-ddd2a17af3e3>", line 5
    with open('D:\Machine_learning_student_project\New folder\student-mat.csv','r') as f:
              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 35-36: malformed \N character escape

Comment: You have to use a raw string to prevent the backslashes being interpreted as escape sequences: `r'…'`.

Comment: thanks a lot :)
Klaus D. 
ShadowRanger
CrazyChucky
   
tdelaney
 
tdelaney
astrochun